# series containing cartesian product into table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series containing the Cartesian product of two arrays and the corresponding labels:

```
  idx1=array(['2m_1y', '6m_1y', '1y_1y', '3y_1y', '5y_1y', '15y_1y', '2m_2y',
       '6m_2y', '1y_2y', '3y_2y', '5y_2y', '15y_2y', '2m_5y', '6m_5y',
       '1y_5y', '3y_5y', '5y_5y', '15y_5y', '2m_10y', '6m_10y', '1y_10y',
       '3y_10y', '5y_10y', '15y_10y'], dtype=object)
```

and values:

```
vals1 = np.random.rand(24,)
```

Is there a way to convert this into a dataframe with index the first part of each label (2m, 6m, 1y, 3y...) and column names the second part (1y, 2y, 5y...) without using a for loop? Efficiency matters as its a big dataset...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, using `str.split` and then `pivot`:

```
>>> idx1 = np.array(['2m_1y', '6m_1y', '1y_1y', '3y_1y', '5y_1y', '15y_1y', '2m_2y',
       '6m_2y', '1y_2y', '3y_2y', '5y_2y', '15y_2y', '2m_5y', '6m_5y',
       '1y_5y', '3y_5y', '5y_5y', '15y_5y', '2m_10y', '6m_10y', '1y_10y',
       '3y_10y', '5y_10y', '15y_10y'], dtype=object)
>>> vals1 = np.arange(len(idx1))
>>> df = pd.Series(idx1).str.split("_", expand=True)
>>> df[2] = vals1
>>> df.pivot(index=0, columns=1, values=2)
1    10y  1y  2y  5y
0                   
15y   23   5  11  17
1y    20   2   8  14
2m    18   0   6  12
3y    21   3   9  15
5y    22   4  10  16
6m    19   1   7  13
```

After this you can sort the columns and indices as you see fit to get them more conveniently ordered.

---

Here, `expand=True` lets us get columns directly from the components (unlike the old days, when we had to use uglier hacks):

```
>>> pd.Series(idx1).str.split("_").head()
0    [2m, 1y]
1    [6m, 1y]
2    [1y, 1y]
3    [3y, 1y]
4    [5y, 1y]
dtype: object
>>> pd.Series(idx1).str.split("_", expand=True).head()
    0   1
0  2m  1y
1  6m  1y
2  1y  1y
3  3y  1y
4  5y  1y
```